# Can't free memory of built drawing cache in Android 3.0

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, bitmap

I have an application with a menu, where the menu items are screenshots from `ViewAnimator`'s views. Everything is working fine. I do the screeshots with this simple sniplet, using drawing cache as written in many examples:

```
    // Drawing cache is off, so build it manually and create scaled bitmap
    layout.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = layout.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm_small = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, item_width, item_height, true);
```

In the same function I try to free all memory used for creating screenshot:

```
    layout.destroyDrawingCache();
    bm.recycle();
    bm = null;
```

But unfortunatelly the garbage collector does not free this bitmap memory. I used also HPROF memory analyzing to find some references to Bitmap that cannot be freed but I did not succeeded. Important information is, that I am developing for Honeycomb Android 3.0, so the screenshots are quite big - every screenshot takes  approx 3MB of memory and do not free it.

I don't understand, why recycle is not working in this example. I suspect, there is some very special problem in my setup: Android 3.0 Honeycomb + Hardware acceleration enabled + Large heap enabled + Using drawing cache. None of the hints I have found are not helping.

Please, can you explain, why `recycle` isn't working in this case? Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I had this issue. it is very bad behavior because bitmap won't free itself. best advice is to use smaller bitmap tiles

and other advice is to use `SoftReference<Bitmap>` to store your data objects. SoftReferenced objects delete themselves when memory is needed. Careful though, you can wind up with missing objects.

the bitmap method though, is just flawed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I know, I can't use smaller bitmaps, because I have to make a screenshot from the whole layout. And the SoftReference solution is also not applicable here I think, because I don't store any reference to the Bitmap :/